# How to create a new variable using debug shell

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I know that eclipse has the debug shell tab, that allows running java code during a breakpoint memory state. Is there a way to create a brand new variable inside the debug shell to be seen inside the variables tab?

For example:

The variables tab has:

```
int a -> 1;

int b -> 2;
```

Then I use debug shell:

```
int c = a + b;
```

Then open variables tab to see c variable value.

Ps: I know that System.out.println() is possible, but in reality, I would like to see a far complex variable that is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of doing that, the debug shell executing just interfere in objects that are currently in the context of the running program.

You can change the values of variables and objects that are currently at **runtime**, but not define new ones on the debug shell. Even if you could do that your new variable will not be anywhere in your code, and if you have it declared, you may have issues declaring the same identifier twice.

If you declare a new variable like in your example ( `int c = a + b;` ), the `c` variable will be available **only inside your debug shell context**.

One workaround to you see the result of the execution is to *inspect* your expression using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> shortcut:

[image]